# 私と同じ or 私のと同じ when comparing possession

Tags: grammar, particle-と, particle-の

[This question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/77402/what-exactly-is-the-function-of-%E3%81%A8-in-this-sentence) made me think.

> 彼の車は私と同じです。
>   His car is the same as **mine**.

Except that isn't a literal translation. A literal translation would be "His car is the same as **me**". But I am not a car.

Would it be incorrect to add a の into this sentence i.e.:

> 彼の車は私**の**と同じです。

A Google search for "私のと同じ" does not result in many convincing hits so I'm assuming it's wrong.

Can we understand this grammatically? Is the の just assumed to be redundant? ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Japanese, 彼の車は私と同じです is a perfectly natural sentence. When you compare two things, this type of omission<sup>*</sup> is extremely common in Japanese, and it can be found even in the most formal writings.

<sup>(* This may seem to be "omission" from the English perspective, but Japanese people may say nothing is omitted.)</sup>

Examples:

- 彼の英語は私より上手です。
  His English is better than mine.
- 地球の体積は月より大きい。
  The volume of the earth is larger than that of the moon.
- この店で売られているリンゴはあの店より美味しい。
  Apples sold at this store are more delicious than those sold at that store.
- 彼の考えは君とは違う。
  His opinion is different from yours.
- 限定版の値段は通常版と同じです。
  The price of the limited edition is the same as that of the regular edition.

(Actually "His car is the same as me" is a common mistake made by Japanese students.)

If there were not many examples of 私のと同じ, it's probably because 私の is relatively colloquial, and in speech の tends to be "omitted" anyway. Instead of の, you can use the stiffer pronoun (の)それ and say the following:

- 彼の車は私の車と同じです。
  彼の車は私のそれと同じです。
- 地球の体積は月の体積より大きい。
  地球の体積は月のそれより大きい。

But sentences like these are found mainly in strict technical documents or translated materials. You can (or should) stick to the shorter versions in most cases.

**EDIT:** Of course you have to avoid "omission" when it causes confusion:

- 君のお父さんは僕のお父さんより背が高い。
  Your father is taller than my father.
- 君のお父さんは僕より背が高い。
  Your father is taller than me.

Comment: Are you sure that 彼の考えは君とは違う etc is natural or grammatical? Can you tell me why I don't see even one example in this page http://english.cheerup.jp/corpus/search?name=%E5%BD%BC+%E6%84%8F%E8%A6%8B+%E7%A7%81+%E9%81%95%E3%81%86

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka That's because you're referring to a [low-quality](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11119577901) E-J parallel corpus which includes literal, old-fashioned or "翻訳調" sentences. Still, there are examples like 私の意見は彼と異なる in the second page. Try [BCCWJ](https://shonagon.ninjal.ac.jp/) and you will find completely different results. You can find examples like 私と同じ苗字, 私と同じ高校, 頭の構造が私と違う, 奴は僕と同じ齢だ and so on and on.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka 田中コーパスって[こんな文](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/63159/5010)も割とありますし、訳としては正しくても「大学生に英文を収集させて翻訳させることで作った対訳集」という時点で、どうしても細かい言い回しが翻訳調・直訳調になっていたり、人称代名詞の使い方などに偏りが出たりするのは避けられません。少なくとも「ごく普通の日本語の使われ方」の証拠として提示するようなものではありません。素直にBCCWJを使いましょう。翻訳文だと「私のそれ」などと言いがちだ、というのは私が回答内で指摘した通りです。

Comment: I accept 「拓哉のクルマ？俺と同じ」 but not 「彼の車は私と同じです」

Comment: @Wakisaka, [Be Nice](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/conduct)でお願いします。