# と usage in 俺と同じ

Tags: particles, particle-と

What is the meaning of と in the following phrase?

> 俺と同じことをするんだ - Do the same thing I do.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/77404/%e7%a7%81%e3%81%a8%e5%90%8c%e3%81%98-or-%e7%a7%81%e3%81%ae%e3%81%a8%e5%90%8c%e3%81%98-when-comparing-possession

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What about this combination of と and や](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/52559/what-about-this-combination-of-%e3%81%a8-and-%e3%82%84) See the last half of [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/57077/5010), too.